# How to handle repetitive HTML code such as headers and footers in Angular 4?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

In my Angular web project I use different two or three types of header in many pages in Angular 4 project. Is there a way to code up your HTML header code and footer code just once and have it included or injected in one or more of your pages. To give some clue I need an alternative for [@Section in ASP.NET MVC Razor](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcinon/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections/) witch in each page we can add an extra code to it (I know this is a server side thing, but I need it in angular client side).
Is there an official/recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create components for that. Something like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myheader',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

And then add it to the template of the other pages where you want to use it (or to the app.component.html if you want it everywhere). Something like:

```
  <myheader></myheader>
```

If you need different data on the header depending on the component you are at, just create a HeaderService, and pass data to the header from the component through it.

Comment: I think that the question is about angularjs and not angular 2+

Comment: The question states Angular 4.

Comment: It is Angular 4, I fixated the tags

Comment: To make the question clear : I need to inject data in the same component based on route URL from within the page. something like Sections in asp.net MVC

Comment: Yes but I want meant was that you can create a service called something like HeaderService and inject it on the Component loaded in that route. On that Component you can then call that service and pass data to it. That will be available on the HeaderComponent (which also has that HeaderService). Declare the provider at app.module.ts so it will be the same across all components.

Comment: @avilao My bad I was misled by the tag.

Comment: @HannounYassir no problem, i didn't even see the tag :)